# React - Best Practice to update parent state in Child component

Tags: reactjs

I have a bool state in the parent component which gets updated from the child. I want to pass the updated state from parent to child for example if a default value was true in the parent and it got changed from child to false, I want the child also to have the same value for the state variable, currently, it holds previous value only which is true. Please suggest the best approach.

adding code snippet:

```
Parent.tsx

export default observer(function Parent(){

const [allowPanelToClose,setAllowPanelToClose]= useState(true);

const UpdateSidepanelClose = function (allowClose:boolean)
{
    if(allowClose !== undefined)
    {
        setAllowPanelToClose(allowClose)
    }
}

return(
<Child allowSidepanelToClose = {UpdateSidepanelClose}
 isSidepanelCloseAllowed ={allowPanelToClose}/>

);
})

Child.tsx

export interface ChildProps{
allowSidepanelToClose : (allowClose: boolean) => void;
isSidepanelCloseAllowed : boolean;
}

function Child({
allowSidepanelToClose,
isSidepanelCloseAllowed}:ChildProps){


useKeypress("Escape",() =>{
if(isSidepanelCloseAllowed === false) // isSidepanelCloseAllowed is coming as true which is issue
{
    // do something
}
}


const onBlur = (event: any)=>{
if (!event.currentTarget.contains(event.relatedTarget))
{
    const isValid = somefunction();
}
if(isvalid)
{
    // perform some operation
}
else{
    allowSidepanelToClose(false);//set parent state from true to false
}
}
}
```

Comment: put the state in the parent. pass both the state and setter to the child as props.

Comment: @nullptr - I am already doing that but latest value of state is not send to child in the props

Comment: we can't help you any more without seeing your code.

Comment: @nullptr- added code snippet

Comment: I'm guessing you are handling event using `onBlur` instead of `onClick`? Since you named handler as `onBlur`

Answer (score 0):

Pass down the state and the setter, so the `foo` and `setFoo`. If the child calls `setFoo`, `foo` will also be updated.

Also, you should include snippets of your current code when asking a question.